# Why is the cyclomatic complexity of this graph 3 instead of 2?

Tags: graph, complexity-theory

I'm reading the wiki about [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity). However, I am curious why the cyclomatic complexity of this graph is 3 instead of 2. Just like this:
[a figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbvhE.png)

I think it's because I don't understand enough about independent paths. Looking forward to a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd path is the straight one without going into any of the two loops present in path
so, 3rd path = start ---> end (without loops as in path 1 and 2)

Comment: Why is this an independent path?